# Why does redirecting stdin in C not work?

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to redirect the stdin from the parent to the child through the pipe "my_pipe", but when I run my program, I do not see the expected results.

When I execute the program, it expects input from the stdin, so why didn't it redirect stdin in dup2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* arguments[] = {"sort", NULL};

    int my_pipe[2];
    if(pipe(my_pipe) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
    }

    pid_t child_id;
    child_id = fork();
    if(child_id == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
    }
    if(child_id == 0) // child process
    {
        close(my_pipe[1]); // child doesn't write
        dup2(0, my_pipe[0]); // redirect stdin

        execvp(argv[0], arguments);

        fprintf(stderr, "Exec failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        close(my_pipe[0]); // parent doesn't read

        char reading_buf[1];
        write(my_pipe[1], "hello", strlen("hello"));
        write(my_pipe[1], "friend", strlen("friend"));
        close(my_pipe[1]);
        wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your arguments to dup2 are backwards. Try `dup2(my_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO)`